# CompletableFuture does not complete on timeout

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I have a method `read` that reads from input stream. I want to complete the future if `read` has not finished after timeout.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   CompletableFuture<?> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
   future
      .thenRunAsync(() -> {
         try {
            read(data);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            future.completeExceptionally(e);
         }
      })
      .orTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   future.join();
}
```

But when I run this code, it does not finish by timeout and waits for input stream anyway.

Comment: I’m not sure CompletableFuture is the best solution to this.  I would use [ExecutorService.invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny%28java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two problems with your code:

1. **Nothing is being executed.** You create a `CompletableFuture` and then invoke `thenRunAsync` on it. The stage created by `thenRunAsync` will only trigger once the *previous stage* has completed. Since you never complete the original `CompletableFuture` this will never happen. You also end up joining on a future that will never complete.
2. **You're joining on the wrong `CompletableFuture`.** Methods such as `thenRunAsync` and `orTimeout` return a *new instance* which creates a sort of "chain" of stages. Each stage is triggered by the completion of its "parent" stage. To fully understand this I recommend reading the documentation of [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html).

Here's an example of your code working how I suspect you want:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(
          () -> {
            try {
              read(data);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
              throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
            }
          })
      .orTimeout(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .join();
}
```

Some notes:

- Used [`CompletableFuture#runAsync(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)) to create a "primordial" stage. This stage will complete when the `Runnable` completes and the common `ForkJoinPool` is used to execute the `Runnable`.
- If and when thrown, the `UncheckedIOException` in the `runAsync` stage will cause the stage to complete exceptionally.
- The `#join()` method is invoked on the instance returned by the `orTimeout(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` call. Now if the timeout elapses the call to `join()` will throw a `CompletionException` wrapping a `TimeoutException`.

**Warning:** The call to `read` is not interrupted<sup>1</sup> when the timeout elapses, meaning it will continue to execute in the background. This is due to the fact `CompletableFuture` has no reference to the executing threads and thus cannot interrupt them.

---

<sup>1. Assuming an interruption would [even have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419311/completablefuture-does-not-complete-on-timeout/60419458?noredirect=1#comment106902187_60419458).</sup>

Comment: `invokeAny` does not help as in the case of OpenJDK/HotSpot, interrupting a read from an `InputStream` was never implemented and nowadays likely will never become implemented due to compatibility.

Comment: Interesting. Removed the alternative suggestion, though I suppose it depends on what "read" is doing in OP's code (e.g. maybe it's using an `InterruptibleChannel` or manually checks for interrupts). Anyway, left the warning regarding completable futures and timeouts as it's still relevant.

Comment: how can I know that CompletableFuture finished by timeout? I don't want to throw TimeoutException to the outside, but I want to return from the method itself

Comment: @a3dsfcv You can catch the `CompletionException` thrown by `join()` and check if its cause is a `TimeoutException`, then do whatever is appropriate. Or you can chain another future which handles exceptions (e.g. `exceptionally`), again inspecting the exception passed to the stage. There's also [`CompletableFuture#completeOnTimeout(T,long,TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeOnTimeout(T,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).